# Repair git -fd clean mistake ? Now seeing "cannot load such file -- less"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, twitter-bootstrap, less

Without understanding, I mistakenly ran `git clean -fd` and saw this:

```
perrys-MacBook-Pro:pc perry_mac$ git clean -fd
Removing log/
Removing public/system/
Removing tmp/
```

Now, when I run  `rails s` and load `http://localhost:3000/` I get:

```
LoadError at /
cannot load such file -- less (in /Users/perry_mac/rails_projects/pc/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
```

Rails Better Errors shows that the exception happens in line 7

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
    2 <html>
    3   <head>
    4     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    5     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Some Cases" %></title>
    6     <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Some Radiology Cases" %>">
    7     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    8     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    9     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   10     <%= yield(:head) %>
   11   </head>
   12   <body>
```

Having now read more on `git clean` I fear I Have made a terrible mistake.  In truth, I don't understand what I may have lost.  The output of

```
Removing log/
Removing public/system/
Removing tmp/
```

... seems innocuous enough.  Am I just one step away from getting my app running again or is it something worse?  I understand that whatever `git clean -fd` removed is unrecoverable.

Here is a [pastebin of my gemfile](http://pastebin.com/eMAHuZ4v), which I think has all the expected gems.
Here is a [pastebin of my .gitignore](http://pastebin.com/JcWsTaFE) file.

I am further confused because `/config/database.yml` is in `.gitignore`, but the file was not deleted.

Please address your answer towards these two points:

1) Based on the output, is there a simple way to know what files I have lost?  What is now gone?
2) Why has my rails app stopped working and what's a good next step to fix it?

ADDENDUM 1:
I ran bundle install
I ran rails `g bootstrap:install less`

```
perrys-MacBook-Pro:pc perry_mac$ rails g bootstrap:install less
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.

      insert  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js.coffee
    conflict  app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
Overwrite /Users/perry_mac/rails_projects/pc/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] Y
       force  app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
      create  config/locales/en.bootstrap.yml
        gsub  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
        gsub  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

Now I see this error:

```
/Users/perry_mac/rails_projects/pc/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss has already been required
```

I think this may be because:

```
app/assetts/stylesheets/application.css
app/assetts/stylesheets/application.css.scss
```

both contain:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

Can you suggest the best way to resolve this cyclical require?

If I delete the contents of `app/assetts/stylesheets/application.css` and save the empty file, my application loads and runs, but there is no styling applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `log/` and `tmp/` isn't that problematic, however, `public/system` can be problematic. Most upload gems put their uploaded files there.

1. no, unless you have a list what was in there before.
2. did you try `bundle install`? Maybe `bundle clean` before as well. Depending on what gem you used to get twitter bootstrap working, follow the install steps again. From that error message, you are at least missing the bootstrap stylesheet files. If you reinstall the relevant gems, it should work again.

Edit concerning your addition:

It seems like the `less` installer created a `application.css`, while you already had a `application.css.scss`. You should be fine by just deleting `application.css` (check the content before). However, I wonder, are you using `scss` and `less` together in a project? That might result in problems in the long run.

Comment: Thanks so much Femaref.  I've updated my question to show some progress.

Comment: Yes. Seems I've had some LESS & SASS confusion as well. Thanks for that help too. I copied all my stylesheets to a save directory out of the css load path.  I then ran "rails g bootstrap:install sass"  This worked.  I then copied back my view specific scss files.  Things look a lot better :-)  As an aside, I did lose images I had upload via the paperclip gem.  Looks like they were (probably correctly) not being tracked by git.  All-in-all major disaster averted.

Comment: as long as it's just your local developer version, it doesn't really matter anyhow.

Comment: I have (still, thankfully) plans to demo the work in a week or so.  I suppose you are right that what I have is not deployed.  Still, it remains important for me to have the app running in development mode.  I am really happy to have benefited from your help.  Thanks again.